# Angular js redirecting from log in page to Dashboard along with json data

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to build a simple app using Angular JS. Here I have two html files (Login.html & Dashboard.html). when I run the Login.html it works well And on the successful log in I need to show the user dashboard with the json data populated(from server) at Login time.

here is my code: (main.js)

```
  var app = angular.module('NovaSchedular', []);
  app.factory('MyService', function() 
  {
  var savedData = {}
    function set(data) 
    {    
     savedData = data;      
     }
    function get() 
    { 
     return savedData;
    }

  return {
  set: set,
  get: get
  }

 });



function LoginController($scope,$http,MyService,$location) 
{

$scope.login = function(str) {
    console.log(".......... login called......");
    var validEmail=validateEmail(email.value);
    if(validEmail && password.value != ""){
    $http.post('./nova/TaskManager/public/user/login?email='+email.value+'&password='+password.value).success(function(data, status)
     {                      
        console.log(data);
        var result=data.response;
        console.log(result); 

        if (result=="success")
        {
            $scope.userId=data.user_id;
            $scope.email=data.email;
            $scope.Name=data.name;
            $scope.password=data.password;
            $scope.Type=data.type;

           console.log("........"+$scope.userId);
           console.log("........"+$scope.email);   
           console.log("........"+$scope.Name);   
           console.log("........"+$scope.password);   
           console.log("........"+$scope.Type); 

           MyService.set(data); 
           console.log(data);

           alert(data.message); 


          window.location.href='./Dashboard.html';  
          //$location.path('./Dashboard.html', data);   

        }
        else
            alert(data.message);
            });
        }             
     }

    }



function DashboardController($scope,$http,MyService) 
{

   $scope.userInfo = MyService.get();    

}
```

here after LOGIN successfully, I am getting the server response (json data) under the LoginController well. Now, further I need these data to be available on the Dashboard page so that dashboard would populate with the respective user data.

I am trying this by using:

```
   window.location.href='./Dashboard.html'; 
   //$location.path('./Dashboard.html', data);
```

but it didn't work for me. It's redirecting to the Dashboard.html well, but doesn't containing the data what I need to pass from the LoginController to the DashboardController. so, that it would available for the Dashboard.html page.

while seeing at the console for the Dashboard.html, it's empty json is showing there.

Don't know what's missing. why it's not passing the data.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this controller code :

```
app.controller('LoginController' function($scope,$http,MyService,$location) 
{

$scope.login = function(credential) {
    console.log(".......... login called......");
    var validEmail=validateEmail(credential.email);
    if(validEmail && credential.password!= ""){
      MyService.login(credential);
    }
  }
  });
```

and this:

```
app.controller('DashboardController',function($scope,$http,MyService) 
{

   $scope.userInfo = MyService.getDashboardData();    

});
```

MyService.js:

```
var app = angular.module('NovaSchedular', []);
  app.factory('MyService', function() 
  {
    var dashboardData;
    var obj={
      login:function(credential){
      $http.post('./nova/TaskManager/public/user/login?email='+credential.email+'&password='+credential.password).success(function(data, status, headers) {
        dashboardData=data;
        window.location.href='./Dashboard.html';
      })
      .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.error('error in loading');
      });
      },
   getDashboardData:function(){
     return dashboardData;
   }
  }

  return {
  login:obj.login,
  getDashboardData:obj.getDashboardData
  }

 });
```

Comment: i think you are not passing credential object from front end in function call. credential has two property credential.email and credential.password.
apply this:
<button ng-click="login(credential)">login</button>
and in ng-model of email field just pass credential.email and in password field just pass credential.password